# Google Calendar API - PHP - "Class 'apiClient' not found"

Tags: php, api, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I'm attempting to set up an application that connects to the Google Calendar API.

So far I have:

- Added the client library and moved the src folder into my working directory
- Updated the Config.php file with all the relevant info from the Google Developer Console
- Set up an index.php file in that folder with the code below, just ran that file, I'm expecting this to produce the OAuth screen to login, however i get a blank screen and an error in my log

> `Class 'apiClient' not found...`

Index.php

```
<?php
    set_include_path('src');
    require_once "Google/Client.php";
    require_once "Google/Service/Calendar.php";

    $apiClient = new apiClient();   <---LINE CAUSING THE ERROR
    $apiClient->setUseObjects(true);
    $service = new apiCalendarService($apiClient);

    if (isset($_SESSION['oauth_access_token'])) {
        $apiClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['oauth_access_token']);
    } else {
        $token = $apiClient->authenticate();
        $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] = $token;
    }      
?>
```

Comment: This example uses Google Analytics API but it might help you get the Oauth flow down.  If you still cant get it to work let me know and I will see if I can make a Calendar tutorial http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/

Answer (score 0):

I just found this problem too.  What's happened is that they've updated the api but not the documentation.  Try changing the includes to

```
$g_Client = new Google_Client();
$g_Cal = new Google_CalendarService($g_Client);
```